# flexbox element not going to the end of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I want the 3rd li item (input) to go to the end of the container, when I use the justify-content: space-between; - nothing happens, I've tried aligning them, but still nothing. 
[image]

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.navContact {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mainNav {
  display: flex;
}

.navitem a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(255, 123, 0);
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="hrNav">
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="mainNav">
    <li class="navitem"><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><input type="text" placeholder="Search..."></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: your first li is not closed properly `<li class="navitem"><a href="#about">About me</a>/<li>` the slash is outside of the closing tag.

Comment: Wow, what a mistake, but this still hasn't fixed the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `flex: 1` in the `ul` and the last item of the `ul`, then set `margin-left: auto` in the last `li` inside `ul` as well

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mainNav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.navitem a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(255, 123, 0);
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.navitem:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<hr class="hrNav">
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="mainNav">
    <li class="navitem"><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="navitem"><input type="text" placeholder="Search..."></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But I don't want the search bar to be so wide, I want it to be on the right side of the container. Literally on the opposite side to contact

Comment: @LeeHoward I thought it you wanted full width, I've updated the answer to meet your requirements

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for confusing you.